# Is there way to reduce the complexity of recursively deleting files in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, filesystems

I have a solution for deleting files in a given directory and keeping first-generation children directories of the parent while deleting the rest.

For example, given this structure:

```
parent
-- child_dir
---- grandchild_dir
```

After running the function, `grandchild_dir` is removed with all of its contents but `child_dir` remains intact.  The problem I have is that the function I am using has a high complexity which I'd like to reduce.

This is for clearing cached Tomcat 8 files where the first-generation subdirectories need to be kept intact due to filesystem constraints.  The cache clearing occurs before the Tomcat server starts (i.e., when it is in a stopped state). I'm afraid that if I delete them and try recreating them then the correct permissions won't be there.  I've tested the function with ServerSpec, and it does work as expected, but I'm afraid that it may spend too much time spinning its wheels upon server startup if there are a lot of files to clear out.

```py
def _clean_directories(path):
    for root, tmp_dirs, tmp_files in os.walk(path):
        for name in tmp_files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
        for name in tmp_dirs:
            if (os.path.join(root, name).count('/') > (path.count('/') + 1)):
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, name))
```

It works as expected, I just don't like the nested `for`'s.

P.S. Is the complexity `O(2n^2)`? (it's been awhile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is linear -- **O(N)** -- on the quantity of `files + directories` in the structure.  You deal with each of these elements once each.

The nested and sequential loops are merely the mechanics you use to reach each one exactly once.